# init.d script - Permission denied

Tags: linux, bash, init

I'm trying to create a init.d script for my server which should start/stop the teamspeak server and some node.js apps using "pm2". Here's my script:

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          my_service
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts/stops all my services
# Description:       starts/stops all my services
### END INIT INFO

echo "running script with argument: $1" >> /log.txt

case "$1" in
  start)
    /usr/local/bin/pm2 resurrect >> /log.txt 2>&1
    /home/teamspeak/ts3server_startscript.sh start >> /log.txt 2>&1
    ;;
  stop)
    /usr/local/bin/pm2 dump >> /log.txt 2>&1
    /usr/local/bin/pm2 delete all >> /log.txt 2>&1
    /home/teamspeak/ts3server_startscript.sh stop >> /log.txt 2>&1
    ;;
esac

echo "done" >> /log.txt
```

As you can see, the scripts logs the stdout & stderr of every command to /log.txt.

The strange thing is, that when I run `/etc/init.d/my_service start/stop` manually, it works great. But when I issue a reboot, the 3 pm2 commands fail. Here's the log i get after a reboot of the machine:

```
running script with argument: stop
exec: 29: : Permission denied
exec: 29: : Permission denied
Stopping the TeamSpeak 3 serverdone
done
running script with argument: start
exec: 29: : Permission denied
Starting the TeamSpeak 3 server
TeamSpeak 3 server started, for details please view the log file
done
```

Do you have any ideas what this could be? Is this related to pm2, or is it a bug in my script?

What I don't get is, why is it different when script gets executed automatically on poweroff/boot from when I start it manually using the shell.

Comment: Do you reallyhave `#! /bin/sh` or do you have `#!/bin/sh`?  The first look for SPACE slash bin slash sh...

Comment: Also, please post the output from ls -l on that script so we can check if the x bit is set.

Comment: Which is line 29? You should setup also the PATH (you are also working on non standard (for init script) directories. Do you set the executable permissions on the script and on pm2?  I assume then in "/etc/init.d/my_service start/stop" you mean space instead of last slash.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your call to pm2 doesn't have sufficient permissions.
Try to run it with sudo if you didn't yet to see if it works.

The error itself seems to come from pm2, because your script does not have a line 29.

Usually, on startup init.d runs with a different user with quite a different set of permissions.

Comment: I don't have sudo installed :( Is there another way to run the script as root?

Comment: Well, then just use the "su" command and run the commands as root that way.

Comment: Won't it ask for the password then?

Comment: Well of course it does. You can only run commands as root if you either have the password or if root set it up so you get root permissions through sudo. As you don't have the latter, you need the root password to run applications as root. If you don't have those, you need to look for other options. Check your permissions for pm, or maybe you just can't write a logfile to the root folder (try to write the log to a folder you have permissions to).

Comment: I have the password, but I don't want my server to be able to restart without me typing in the password everytime. So the only solution is installing sudo?

Comment: Well, you should actually exhaust the other options. Run all the commands by hand and check the result, if it shows an error, try to analyze why it shows the error. One error might be you don't have sufficient permissions for executing pm2, the other error might be you can't write files to /, try to check for both first, and try to think of other things. If you can't think of anything else, you might install sudo. That being said, just using sudo doesn't mean you can restart without a password, it means you can restart using YOUR password instead of ROOTs password.

Comment: Actually, I'm root so I have all the permissions I want. I of course can write to the / directory, otherwise my logfile would not have been created. I also can run the pm2 command withouth problem, if i run it from the shell. It only does not work when the script gets executed from the init system. Do you know what user starts init scripts?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that, you can use whoami in a script when booting and log the result to a folder if you want to.

Comment: whoami says it's root :S That's a really weird thing. Maybe I should ask the devs of pm2 for help.. Thank you!!